# Получить позицию выбранного элемента в RecyclerView из Activity

Tags: java, android

**GoodsAdapter.java**

```
public class GoodsAdapter extends MultiChoiceAdapter<GoodsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final String TAG = "TDT-GoodsAdapter";
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final List<GoodModel> mGoodsList;
    private int mRowSelected = -1;
//    private final getSelectedItem mSelectedItem;

//    public interface getSelectedItem {
//        void onItemClick(GoodsAdapter holder, int position);
//    }

    public GoodsAdapter(List<GoodModel> mGoodsList, Context mContext) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.mGoodsList = mGoodsList;
//        this.mSelectedItem = selectedItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        GoodModel goodItem = mGoodsList.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " + goodItem.getName());
        holder.goodName.setText(goodItem.getName());
        holder.goodName.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            mRowSelected = position;
//            mSelectedItem.onItemClick(this, position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
        if (mRowSelected == position) {
            holder.goodName.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            holder.goodName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GoodsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.good_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mGoodsList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView goodName;


        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            goodName = view.findViewById(R.id.good_name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Goods.java**

```
public class Goods extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<GoodModel>> {
    private final String TAG = "TDT-Goods";
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private final Context mContext;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private final ACProgressFlower mDialog;

    public Goods(RecyclerView recyclerView, Activity activity) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mContext = activity;
        mDialog = new ACProgressFlower.Builder(activity)
                .direction(ACProgressConstant.DIRECT_CLOCKWISE)
                .themeColor(Color.WHITE)
                .text("Работаем")
                .fadeColor(Color.DKGRAY).textSize(25).build();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<GoodModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        TDTApi tdtService = TDTClient.getTDTClient().create(TDTApi.class);
        Call<GoodsModel> call = tdtService.getGoods(params[0], params[1]);
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: params[0]: " + params[0] + ", params[1]: " + params[1]);
        try {
            Response<GoodsModel> rp = call.execute();
            return rp.body().getGoods();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<GoodModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (mDialog.isShowing()) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
        if (result != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: params[0]: " + result.toString());
            GoodsAdapter goodsAdapter = new GoodsAdapter(result, mContext);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(goodsAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView mGoodsList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner foldersSpinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mGoodsList = findViewById(R.id.goods_list);
        Button findGood = findViewById(R.id.find_good);
        Button print = findViewById(R.id.print);
        EditText goodSearchText = findViewById(R.id.good_search_text);

        // Поиск складов
        new Folders(foldersSpinner, this).execute();

        // Поиск товара
        findGood.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            String searchGoodText = goodSearchText.getText().toString();
            if (foldersSpinner.getCount() > 0 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(searchGoodText)) {
                FolderModel selectedFolder = (FolderModel) foldersSpinner.getSelectedItem();
                String idFolder = selectedFolder.getId();
                mGoodsList.setAdapter(null);

                new Goods(mGoodsList, this).execute(idFolder, searchGoodText);
            }
        });

        // Печать ценника
        print.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // КАК ПОЛУЧИТЬ ПОЗИЦИЮ ИЗ RecyclerView??
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Вопрос. Как получить номер позиции из RecyclerView в Activity?

Comment: В классе ViewHolder, который в RecyclerView, есть метод getAdapterPosition();

Comment: Это я знаю. Как мне позицию получить в MainActivity?

Comment: Можно попробовать получить позицию еще в адаптере, а потом передать ее в main activity, только зачем?